# Python Sqlite Escape String Select Column

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm trying to find a way to insert a value into my Sqlite query for selecting a column.

What I have working now is;

```
def ChangeItemQuantity(self, item_name, incrament_quantity):
    try:
        # Change given item quantity in database
        self.c.execute('''
             SELECT quantity
             FROM items
             WHERE itemName=?
             ''',(item_name,))
        current_quantity = self.c.fetchone()
        new_quantity = current_quantity[0] + incrament_quantity
        self.c.execute('''
             UPDATE items
             SET quantity = ?
             WHERE itemName=?
             ''',(new_quantity, item_name))
        self.conn.commit()
```

This works for changing a value in the `quantity` column, but I would like to reuse this method for changing the value in another column also, `alertLevel`.

So I would like to pass in the column name, something like this;

```
def ChangeItemQuantity(self, column_name, item_name, incrament_quantity):
    try:
        self.c.execute('''
             SELECT ?
             FROM items
             WHERE itemName=?
             ''',(column_name, item_name))
```

I've also tried;

```
        self.c.execute('''
             SELECT {}
             FROM items
             WHERE itemName={}
             '''.format(column_name, item_name))
```

Thank you for all your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *cannot parameterize the column or table names*. You have to use string formatting:

```
def ChangeItemQuantity(self, column_name, item_name, incrament_quantity):
    try:
        self.c.execute('''
             SELECT {column_name}
             FROM items
             WHERE itemName=?
             '''.format(column_name=column_name), (item_name,))
```

Make sure though that you either trust your source, or validate the column name before inserting into the query.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, but how is this any different than the `.format` that I have tried?

Comment: @JohnBoy it's different. You have to use formatting for column or table names, but the rest of the query should still be parameterized.

Comment: Ok, thank you! Would the `.format()` used here be vulnerable to SQL injection?

Comment: @JohnBoy exactly, you have to validate/escape the column name.

Comment: by validate you mean `colum_name=colum_name`? Thank you again for your help.

Comment: @JohnBoy no, I mean checking if it's value meets certain security requirements. For instance, you may check that it contains alphanumeric characters only.